# What ist a ContactList in ActiveCampaign?

Tags: activecampaign

What is a ContactList in ActiveCampaign API v3 which is returned on a GET request?

```
GET api/3/contacts?include=contactLists.list,organization
```

[image]

I could not find any information on the contact list neither in the API nor the web application (https://User-Account.activehosted.com) itself. However, the lists are documented and are accessible via the web application.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

ContactList is the list into which the contact is added which you can see here https://User-Account.activehosted.com/admin/main.php?action=list. By default, the contacts won't be added to any of the lists unless you have explicitly specified any list when adding the contact or you have to manually add the contact to a list from the contacts page (https://User-Account.activehosted.com/app/contacts).

Hope that answers your question. Please ask if you have any doubts.

Comment: An update to the previous comment:

ContactLists  in the response of your GET request is just an array to store the reference of the lists into which the contact is added. The value of the 'list' parameter in the array 'ContactLists' is actually the id of the lists into which the contact is added.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `"contactList"` ist the relational connection between contacts and lists.

It's an n:m relation and therefore looks like

`contact` < `contactList` > `list`

A `contactList` entry holds a unique identifier, the contact's and list's id. (plus status and some more information)

```
contactList:
 id = unique relation id
 contact = contact.id
 list = list.id
```

P.S.: `list` is the list itself.